# Operator norm estimate

Tags: hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

> Let $H$ be a Hilbert space with orthonormal basis  $(e_{j})_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$. Furthermore, let $B\colon H\rightarrow C[a,b]$ be a bounded operator. According to the Riesz-Frechet theorem there is a unique $k_{x}\in H$ with $\langle h,k_x\rangle=(Bh)(x)$ and all $h \in H$.
>
> Show that $\|k_{x}\|\leq \|B\|_{H\rightarrow C[a,b]}<\infty.$

I am really confused by this if I use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality I don't get anywhere

$$ \|Bh\|=\langle h,k_{x}\rangle|\leq\|h\|\|k_{x}\|.$$
or

$$\|Bh\|\leq\|B\|\|h\|.$$

How do I proceed? I don't see how I would get the inequality or that it is $<\infty$?

Comment: By the Riesz-Frechet theorem, do you mean the Riesz representation theorem? If so, that only applies when $B$ is a linear functional mapping $H$ to $\mathbb C$ or $\mathbb R$, not a Banach space. (I'm pretty sure $\mathcal C[a,b]$ is a Banach space...)

Comment: Yes but if I am not mistaken you can define the linear continuous map $L_{x}:H\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ by
 $ L_{x}(f):=T(f)(x)=(Tf)(x).$ Then you can apply the Riesz-Frechet theorem. But that fact is given it is the estimation that I am struggling with. I don't see what strategy I should take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this doesn't apply to all problems involving inner product spaces, one of the common ways to estimate the norm of something is to instead estimate its norm squared:

$$ \|k_x\|^2 = | \langle k_x, k_x \rangle| = |Bk_x(x)| \le \|Bk_x\|_{C[a,b]} \le \|B\|_{op} \|k_x\|$$

where the operator norm $\|B\|_{op}$ is finite by assumption.

Comment: Thank you very much is the fact that $\|B\|_{H\rightarrow C[a,b]}<\infty$ now trivial or do I have to proof this this is not clear to me

Comment: $\|B\|_{H \rightarrow C[a,b]}$ is what I'm calling $\|B\|_{op}$ above, and it is finite because the problem stated that $B$ was a bounded operator.